# how to declare a method in parent abstract class so that it can be accessed by children?

Tags: java, inheritance, access-modifiers

In Java, I have an abstract class with a method implemented (not abstract) which I want to be accessible by other classes which extend it, but not by everyone else in the package..

I think this is not possible, because private keeps it private, public and protected expose it too much..

How would you approach the problem? Reimplementing the same method in all the extended classes is out of discussion.. is there a way to access the parent methods?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use protected and make a package that contains only the abstract class and it's subclasses. Don't put any other classes in that package that shouldn't have access to protected methods.

If your concern is that someone else might create a new class in that package and start accessing protected methods, there really isn't a language construct to prevent that. You  have either trust your other developers or have a stringent peer review process.

Comment: If the method is protected you don't have to put the subclasses in the same package...

Comment: @pgras This is true, but it's good practice to keep them in either the same package or a subpackage to avoid cyclic dependencies between packages.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the method to be accessible by anything that extends the class then `protected` is the modifier you want. This is what it is for.

Answer (score 2):

`but not by everyone else in the package..` That's not possible. You can use `protected` access to allow access for subclasses but that will also include access for every class in the same package.